# Will Google Cloud SDK upgrade to Cloud SQL Proxy 2.x?

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

I know I can install the Google Cloud SQL Proxy as a Google Cloud SDK component like this, which currently (Google Cloud SDK 433.0.1) gets me Cloud SQL 1.x:

```
❯ gcloud components install cloud_sql_proxy
❯ cloud_sql_proxy --version
Cloud SQL Auth proxy: 1.27.0+darwin.amd64
```

But then I found that https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-instance-auth-proxy#install-proxy recommends downloading the Cloud SQL Proxy 2.x as a stand-alone binary without using `gcloud components`:

```
❯ curl -o cloud-sql-proxy https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-sql-connectors/cloud-sql-proxy/v2.3.0/cloud-sql-proxy.darwin.amd64
❯ chmod +x cloud-sql-proxy
❯ ./cloud-sql-proxy --version
cloud-sql-proxy version 2.3.0+darwin.amd64
```

I would prefer to keep the Cloud SQL Proxy updated automatically along with Google Cloud SDK and not having to keep it up-to-date manually. Are there any plans to provide Cloud SQL Proxy 2.x via `gcloud components`?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a feature request for this: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy/issues/1659